# Connection from Mexico through Dallas onto Canada

Tags: bookings

Do I go through immigration and customs in Dallas and through security to take the Toronto flight?

Comment: Depending on what your travel plans are, and if you're not from Canada, and plan to be in México and Canada for more than 90 days (combined) be aware that the US can (at the discretion of whoever you next deal with at US Border control) , treat you as though you have overstayed being in the US even though you were only there a day or so (e.g., not let you in)

Comment: @FlyingKiwi that only applies to visa waiver program travelers.  Travelers with visas, including tourist and business visitor visas, don't need to worry about it.  First, because B-visa visitors are admitted for six months, and second, because the relevant regulation applies only to the VWP.

Comment: @phoog indeed, that's correct.

Comment: And even on VWP, it is extremely unlikely that US CBP would regard two transits through the USA as a violation. The point of the rule is to stop somebody spending 90 days in the US, hopping over the Canadian border and coming back to claim another 90 days. It is clear that, in this situation, the asker is not making a fake visit to Canada to extend a stay in the US; rather, they are making a brief stop in the US on their way to a genuine visit to Canada.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  All transits between other countries, via US airports, require you to clear US Customs and Immigration checks.